# flex invalidation mechanism

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Adobe help document said, "When a component calls an invalidation method, it signals to Flex that the component must be updated. When multiple components call invalidation methods, Flex coordinates updates so that they all occur together during the next screen update."

So what does `"next screen update"` mean? I am confused about the invalidation, does it mean the Flex will execute measure(), commitProperties(), updateDisplayList() period where marks invalidateSize(), invalidateProperties(), invalidateDisplayList()？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373140/why-does-updatedisplaylist-stop-happening-in-flex/3373388#3373388) has the links you are looking for. Read up on the elastic racetrack and check out Deepa's presentation on the flex lifecycle.